# Finding limit of $x_n$=$(1-1/(2^2))(1-1/(3^2))...(1-1/(n^2))$

Tags: real-analysis

Ok so the question is in the title, and I'm just trying to do some practice problems and this question has me stumped.  I do realize that as n goes to infinity, the brackets at the end will always be 1, but I have a hunch that the limit is 0, I just don't know how to prove it.  Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: $$1-\frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{k^2-1}{k^2} = \frac{(k-1)(k+1)}{k^2}$$

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite each $1-\frac{1}{k^2}$ as $\frac{(k-1)(k+1)}{k^2}$ and observe the mass cancellations. It will be useful to do this explicitly for say the product of the first $5$ terms.

$$\left(\frac{3}{2}\frac{4}{3}\frac{5}{4}\cdots\frac{n}{n-1}\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}\frac{3}{4}\cdots\frac{n-2}{n-1}\frac{n-1}{n}\right)$$

After mass cancellations, pull the $$\frac{n+1}{2}\text{ and }\frac{1}{n}$$

$$\frac{n+1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{n}$$

Limit of this function tending to infinity $= 1/2$.